# skip last record in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have 37 rows in a table how can i show 36 rows

```
SELECT c.CommonContentId      
      ,c.Content_Code      
      ,c.Content_Name      
      ,c.Seo_Name      
      ,c.[Description]      
      ,c.Link     
      ,c.Page_Path      
      ,c.ContentType_Code      
      ,c.Creation_Date      
      ,c.Is_Active      
      ,c.Last_Update_Date      
      ,c.Category_Code      
      ,c.Category_Code_Style  
      ,c.Content_Script      
      ,c.Content_Website      
      ,c.Logo_Path      
      ,c.Case_Study      
      ,c.SortOrder      
      ,c.Tags      
      ,c.Vl_Page_Image_Url 
      ,c.Is_Show_Vl_Pages,    
      ,ct.ContentType_Name    
      ,cat.Category_Name    
      ,cat1.Category_Name as Category_Name_Style
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY c.ContentType_Code ASC, c.Content_Code DESC) as Record_No
      ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY c.ContentType_Code ASC, c.Content_Code DESC) % 3 = 0 
             THEN '' ELSE '' END as Class       
      ,c.SortOrder      
      , Case WHEN len(logo_path) > 1 
               then 'imagePadded' 
            else '' end as Tetimonial_Image_Css
      ,Case when c.Link like '%vidyard%' 
              then 'http://play.vidyard.com/'+c.Page_Path+'' 
           else 'http://vimeo.com/'+c.Page_Path+'' end   as videolinks  

FROM Content c     
INNER JOIN  ContentType ct    ON c.ContentType_Code = ct.ContentType_Code       
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category cat  ON c.Category_Code = cat.Category_Code       
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category cat1 ON c.Category_Code_Style = cat1.Category_Code    
WHERE c.Is_Active = 1
```

Comment: Removed the `plsql` tag as there is no PL/SQL in this question and the query is clearly for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear if you want an answer for *Oracle* or *MS SQL server*, as your question is tagged both with PL/SQL and SQL-server.

As far as I know, there is no cross-vendor syntax to achieve that goal.

### MS SQL

Use the [`TOP` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb686896%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP (36)
...
```

### Oracle

For Oracle, one way to do it is simply using the [pseudo-column `ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm):

```
SELECT ....
WHERE ROWNUM <= 36
```

Starting with Oracle 12c (I think), you might use the [`FETCH` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55645):

```
SELECT ...
FETCH FIRST 36 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score -1):

I will use [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Then skip the last row. This will work for table with any number of records, and truely "skip last record in sql server table" without using any magic number.

```
WITH CTE AS
(

    -- Your SQL Statement here...

) 

Select * from CTE
where Record_No <> (SELECT Count(*) from CTE)
```